# Data from View to controller is passing null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this View page where I am getting Current Logged In UserId of User, date and page title and I am passing these values to the controller to save into my DB table. But the values are passing null to the controller from view. I am not sure whether I can get the values like this and pass to controller and store in DB.

View :

```
  @model Sample.Models.UserLog
   @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
         @using (Html.BeginForm("Idex", "Index", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
      {

     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<br/>
<br/>

<p >@ViewBag.Title</p>
<P>@User.Identity.Name</P>
<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @Value = @DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() })</p>
```

}

Controller :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private readonly UserLogEntities _db = new UserLogEntities();


    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "Name, Date, Title")]  UserLog log)
    {
        ViewBag.UserName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            _db.UserActivityLogs.Add(log);
            _db.Entry(log).State = EntityState.Added;
            _db.SaveChanges();

        }
        return View();
    }
```

}

Model :

```
public partial class UserLog
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string EndPoint { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/AyeU9M

If you put a breakpoint in the Post Action, you will see values in Action returned from View
Table

```
CREATE TABLE [AHCCCS\KXBlau].[UserLog](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [EndPoint] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Controller/View Model

```
public class UserLogViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string EndPoint { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly SMARTEntities3 _db = new SMARTEntities3();

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyIndex([Bind(Include = "UserName, EndPoint, Date")]  UserLogViewModel log)
    {
        ViewBag.UserName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //from viewmodel to object
            UserLog userLog = new UserLog { Date = DateTime.Parse(log.Date), EndPoint = log.EndPoint, 
                UserName = log.UserName };

            _db.UserLogs.Add(userLog);
            _db.Entry(log).State = EntityState.Added;
            _db.SaveChanges();

        }
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Tut142()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View

```
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.UserLogViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut142</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("MyIndex", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <br />
        <br />
        <p>@User.Identity.Name</p>
        <p>
            @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @Value = @DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() })*@
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndPoint)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndPoint)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date)
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    }
</body>
</html>
```